# at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" in node.js.how to deal with it?

Tags: node.js

> 2020-07-21T06:54:58.030920+00:00 heroku[router]:

```
at=error code=H12
> desc="Request timeout"
```

method=GET path="/Recipies"

> host=desolate-beach-26163.herokuapp.com
> request_id=25f963a1-ce9e-43c6-a054-72c8a7a33ea8 fwd="157.36.134.120"
> dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
> protocol=https`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [H12 "Request timeout" in Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/AXOSFIXN/why-am-i-getting-h12-request-timeout-errors-in-nodejs) is caused by long running actions.

The Heroku docs ([here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#http-timeouts)) indicate that the server has 30 seconds to respond before the H12 timeout error occurs. *There is no configuration or parameter to increase this*. The *only* way to extend that is for the server or client to send *some* data to trigger a 55 second extension.  Every time you send data you have 55 seconds to send more data (i.e. it's a rolling window). The browser might someday be able to use [ReadableStreams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request#browser_compatibility) as a hack to keep it alive, but as of 2022, your best bet is probably going to be server-side.  If you are sending JSON, one hack would be to add middleware on the server-side to send whitespace every few seconds to avoid the disconnect ([example](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/05/15/extending-heroku-timeout-node/)).

**Database common causes**

I'm not sure if you're pulling data from a database with this route, but the H12 error is a [common issue when connecting to data sources from node.js on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581743/request-timeout-on-heroku).

First, check your database connection string, just to make sure that the configuration hasn't been affected.  At the beginning of your app (server.js) you can log out the database URL:

```
console.log("Database_URL", process.env.DATABASE_URL);
```

After hitting the route (in your case, "/Recipies"), check the logs from your project's directory:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Your connection string should look something like:

```
postgres://qi34l...545b4@ec2-3-63-192-23.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/aj48e4ewfjow34
```

If it doesn't, check your package.json, Procfile, and your index.js file for something that might overwrite DATABASE_URL.

You can verify the connection string by connecting via the "psql" command line tool with your url.  It will look something like this (but replace the URL with your connection string) -

```
psql postgres://qi34l...545b4@ec2-3-63-192-23.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/aj48e4ewfjow34
```

If you can connect, it's probably an issue with the way that the postgresql library is being initialized.  If you're using the latest "node-postgres" ("pg"), make sure that you have ssl rejectUnauthorized set to false:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});
```

Comment: isn't there a way to increase timeout for heroku apps?

Comment: Hi @ShivamSahil. Unfortunately, no. Please see updated answer.